# NSIS $TEMP Has Different Value

Tags: windows, installation, nsis, temp, runonce

I have been noticed **$TEMP** param has different value when you:

- run the installer.exe manually (by double clicking)
- run from Application with Admin rights.

Running manually will result $TEMP = **C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp**

Running from App with Admin rights = **C:/Windows/Temp**

**CONDITION:**

I have an installer that requires *system reboot* to finish the process.

To achieve that, I make a copy of installer in the $TEMP, and put the path in *RunOnce*

**PROBLEM:**

The function works fine (after reboot, the program is updated with new version).

However, at the end of installation process, I am unable to delete the copy of installer because the $TEMP = **C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp** when running the installer by *RunOnce*.

In fact, the copy of installer is located in **C:/Windows/Temp**

**QUESTION:**

Is it possible to force the $TEMP to always be = **C:/Windows/Temp** ?

Is there any better solution to workaround the case of installation with system reboot?

Comment: What is your `RequestExecutionLevel` attribute set to?

Answer (score 5):

NSIS gets its `$Temp` variable like this:

First it tries [`GetTempPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppatha). That function tries (in order): `%TMP%`, `%TEMP%`, `%USERPROFILE%`, and `%WINDIR%`, and it returns the first variable that exists.

NSIS then tries to write to this directory and if that fails NSIS uses `%WINDIR%\Temp`.

Admin vs non-admin nor UAC elevation is not really the cause of what you are seeing. Sounds more like a configuration or Anti-Virus issue.

You can force `$Temp` to a specific directory if you really want to in NSIS 3:

```
Function .onInit
UnsafeStrCpy $Temp "$Windir\Temp"
CreateDirectory $Temp
/* 
#--# Uncomment to apply the same %TEMP% to child processes #--#
System::Call 'KERNEL32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t"TEMP",t"$Temp")'
System::Call 'KERNEL32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t"TMP",t"$Temp")'
*/
FunctionEnd
```

I don't actually understand your issue though because the RunOnce entry can tell what it's path is by using `$ExePath`.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's not really because of Admin rights. Because the installer is executed by other app (update manager), which is out of my scope. So, I'm not really sure how it becomes C:/Windows/Temp. Anyway, I did a workaround by putting the copy of installer in ProgramFiles, instead of Temp. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: It probably inherited this temp from the update manager. You can inspect the environment of a process with Process Explorer.